# Extract maximum value from matrix based on random sample by month

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, max

I have a distance matrix df1 showing the distances between 8 locations a:h

```
x <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7), b=c(1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6),
                  c=c(2,1,0,1,2,3,4,5), d=c(3,2,1,0,1,2,3,4),
                  e=c(4,3,2,1,0,1,2,3), f=c(5,4,3,2,1,0,1,2),
                  g=c(6,5,4,3,2,1,0,1), h=c(7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0),
                  row.names=x)

> df1
  a b c d e f g h
a 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
b 1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6
c 2 1 0 1 2 3 4 5
d 3 2 1 0 1 2 3 4
e 4 3 2 1 0 1 2 3
f 5 4 3 2 1 0 1 2
g 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 1
h 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

I also have another dataframe df2 showing the locations recorded in each month

```
df2 <- data.frame(Month=c(rep(11,3),rep(12,4),rep(1,3)),
                  Location=sample(letters[1:8],10,replace=T))

> df2
   Month Location
1     11        c
2     11        a
3     11        d
4     12        f
5     12        c
6     12        f
7     12        a
8      1        b
9      1        b
10     1        h
```

I want to extract the maximum distance between recorded locations for each month. The output should look something like this

```
  Month Max.Distance
1    11            3
2    12            5
3     1            6
```

I would also be interested in calculating cumulative distance between locations for each month, the output of which would look like:

```
  Month Cum.Distance
1    11            5
2    12           11
3     1            6
```

I hope this makes sense. I've considered using a for loop but my knowledge of R loops is limited so any help would be greatly appreciated. Many thanks!

Comment: Hi Ronak df1 is symmetrical along the x=y line so it shouldn't matter whether the calculation is achieved row-wise or column-wise. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I define the data frames, as per your example.

```
x <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h")
df1 <- data.frame(a=c(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7), b=c(1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6),
                  c=c(2,1,0,1,2,3,4,5), d=c(3,2,1,0,1,2,3,4),
                  e=c(4,3,2,1,0,1,2,3), f=c(5,4,3,2,1,0,1,2),
                  g=c(6,5,4,3,2,1,0,1), h=c(7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0),
                  row.names=x)

df2 <- data.frame(Month=c(rep(11,3),rep(12,4),rep(1,3)),
                  Location=sample(letters[1:8],10,replace=T))

#    Month Location
# 1     11        d
# 2     11        c
# 3     11        h
# 4     12        e
# 5     12        c
# 6     12        b
# 7     12        h
# 8      1        h
# 9      1        g
# 10     1        b
```

Next, I define a function that finds all possible combinations of locations for month `m` and then looks for the maximum distance.

```
# Find maximum distance
max_dist <- function(m){
  # Check if it's just one location
  if(sum(df2$Month == m) == 1)return(0)

  # Get all combinations of locations for given month
  tmp <- t(combn(match(df2$Location[df2$Month == m], rownames(df1)), 2))

  # Get max value from these location combinations
  max(df1[tmp[, 1], tmp[, 2]])
}
```

Finally, I apply the function to all months in `df2` and repackage as a data frame.

```
# Run function on all months
data.frame(month = unique(df2$Month), max_dist = unlist(lapply(unique(df2$Month), max_dist)))

#   month max_dist
# 1    11        5
# 2    12        6
# 3     1        6
```

---

The following provides the total distance:

```
tot_dist <- function(m){
  tmp <- match(df2$Location[df2$Month == m], rownames(df1))  
  sum(df1[cbind(head(tmp, -1), tail(tmp, -1))])
}
```

---

In response to you comment, I think this works:

```
# Find maximum distance
max_dist <- function(m){
  # Check if it's just one location
  if(sum(df2$Month == m) == 1)return(0)

  # Get all locations
  locs <- which(df2$Month == m)
  if(tail(which(df2$Month == m), 1) != nrow(df2))locs <- c(locs, tail(which(df2$Month == m), 1) + 1)

  # Get all combinations of locations for given month
  tmp <- t(combn(match(df2$Location[locs], rownames(df1)), 2))

  # Get max value from these location combinations
  max(df1[tmp[, 1], tmp[, 2]])
}
```

Essentially, it just gets the next row in addition to those for month `m` providing there is another row. The total distance equivalent is as follows:

```
tot_dist <- function(m){
  # Get all locations
  locs <- which(df2$Month == m)
  if(tail(which(df2$Month == m), 1) != nrow(df2))locs <- c(locs, tail(which(df2$Month == m), 1) + 1)

  tmp <- match(df2$Location[locs], rownames(df1))  
  sum(df1[cbind(head(tmp, -1), tail(tmp, -1))])
}
```

Comment: Thank you Lyngbakr this is really helpful!
My next query is whether the cumulative distance can be calculated for each month. So for example, for df2 illustrated in your example, the cumulative distance for month 11 would be calculated by summing the distance from d to c with the distance from c to h, so (d:c)+(c:h) = 6.

Comment: @EmilyWinter I've added a function to my solution that does that.

Comment: this is great, thank you. There is one problem however in that when you run your max_dist function on a new version of df2 that contains only one location record for each month it gives an erroneous output for these months. 
Try it using df2 <- data.frame(Month=c(rep(11,1),rep(12,1),rep(1,1)), Location=sample(letters[1:8],3,replace=T)) and you will see what I mean. The max_dist should be 0 for each month. I hope that makes sense

Comment: @EmilyWinter I think I've fixed it.

Comment: Hello again, this code has been working very well, but I'd like to modify it. Is it possible to calculate the max_dist and tot_dist for the locations in each month plus the first location in the following month? So, in your example, the max_dist/tot_dist for month 11 would be calculated for locations d,c,h AND e. Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: @EmilyWinter I've edited my answer. If it does the job, feel free to accept the answer by clicking the check mark on the left.

Answer (score 0):

```
df2 <- read.table(text = "
Month Location
1     11        c
2     11        a
3     11        d
4     12        f
5     12        c
6     12        f
7     12        a
8      1        b
9      1        b
10     1        h", h = T)

aggregate(Location ~ Month, df2, function(j) diff(range(sapply(j, function(i) grep(i, letters)))))

  Month Location
1     1        6
2    11        3
3    12        5
```

For your 2nd objective:

```
aggregate(Location ~ Month, df2, function(j) sum(abs(diff(sapply(j, function(i) grep(i, letters))))))

  Month Location
1     1        6
2    11        5
3    12       11
```

Comment: Thank you Len, do you know how this might be edited to calculate the cumulative distance between each location in each month?

Comment: What exactly do you want? And what order of months would you like to apply?

Comment: I would like to sum the distances between each location in the order they appear in the dataframe. So in your example, for month 11, the cumulative distance would equate to the distance from c to a plus the distance from a to d. 
 The order of months is not important although it would be useful if they were kept in the original order.

Comment: I see now, I have added it to my answer. It was almost the same code as for your first objective.